# Is uncountable union of $\sigma$-algebra necessarily algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

It is well known that infinite union of $\sigma$-algebra is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra.

But then I read this:

> The countable union of a non-decreasing sequence of σ-algebras is an algebra.

I am not sure why **countable** union is needed here.
Is there any example that uncountable union of $\sigma$-algebra that is not an **algebra**?

Comment: The key word here is "non-decreasing sequence", not "countable".

Comment: @EricWofsey I understand that "non-decreasing" is the key. I just got confused why the author added "countable" here. Might it be just a typo?

Comment: Probably they define "sequence" to mean a sequence indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, so for them "countable" is automatic in this context.  I'm writing an answer elaborating on this.

Comment: @ablmf: It’s probably to avoid any misunderstanding resulting from the use of *sequence*: some would understand *sequence* to mean only $\omega$-sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Countability is totally irrelevant here, but what is essential is that the algebras form a "non-decreasing sequence".  What this should mean for more general (not necessarily countable) collections is that the algebras you are taking the union of are totally ordered under inclusion.  More precisely, we have the following:

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{C}$ be any nonempty set of algebras on $X$ such that for any $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$, either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.  Then $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ is also an algebra.

To prove this, first note that since $\mathcal{C}$ is nonempty, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$.  Now suppose $S,T\in\bigcup\mathcal{C}$.  Then for some $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$, $S\in A$ and $T\in B$.  Without loss of generality, $A\subseteq B$.  Then $S,T\in B$, so $S\cup T, S\cap T$, and $X\setminus S$ are all in $B$.  Thus they are all in $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$, which says that $\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra.

If you remove the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is totally ordered, then this result can fail already for finite unions, even if the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are $\sigma$-algebras.  For instance, take $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{A,B\}$ where $A=\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1,2\},X\}$ and $B=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{0,2\},X\}$.

(Actually, you don't quite need $\mathcal{C}$ to be totally ordered; it suffices for it to be *directed*: for any $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$, there exists $C\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A,B\subseteq C$.  The proof is similar.)